# draw polygon with different line width wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

i am writing code in wxpython 3.0.0 and python 2.7. I am adding irregular polygon using points in

```
poly = FloatCanvas.Polygon(...)
self.Canvas.AddObject(poly)
self.Canvas.Draw()
```

[image: Irregular polygon]
consider this shape closed.

I want to make width of specific lines in polygon half of other normal lines. please can anyone know how make it a single object and attain this output. thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you use some other module for drawing polygon. like Matplotlib...

Comment: You might want to ask on the float canvas mailing list. I am not sure that is supported though. Matplotlib can be embedded in wxPython, so I agree that that is an option.

Comment: Another library that's fairly easy to use, would be `PyCairo`, which is a SVG-based tool for drawing - vector-based drawings, but they can be converted to bitmaps. (Warning, the RGBA bytes are generally reversed to ABGR, but that's easily fixed).